# How to create custom serialization in Kotlin with java.io.serializable

Tags: java, kotlin, serialization, java-io, kotlinx.serialization

I am attempting to serialize with java.io.Serializable a Kotlin class that is **already serializable** with [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization). The java serialization will not work out of the box because some fields in the class are not serializable by default. But, there are already adapters for the kotlix.serialization. So, I am trying to add custom read and write methods (using the [Externalizable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) interface) to the class, so that I can fallback to the kotlinx.serialization.
Basicly it is something like this:

```
@Serializable
data class Foo(
    val a: A \\ A is serializable in kotlinx and not in java.io
    ...
    val z: Z \\ This is serializable in java.io
)
```

I tried to do the following in Kotlin:

```
@Serializable
data class Foo(
    val a: A \\ A is serializable in kotlinx and not in java.io
    ...
    val z: Z \\ This is serializable in java.io
): java.io.Externalizable {
    override fun writeExternal(out: ObjectOutput?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun readExternal(`in`: ObjectInput?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

I can't replace the values of the class in the read methods (they are immutable). This means I can't use serializable directly either. Is there a builtin way to do this?